# google-cloud-dataflow : How to read data from a Database and write to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I need to setup a data pipeline from some source databases like Oracle, MySQL and load the data to BigQuery.

How can I use google-cloud-dataflow to read data from a database(jdbc connection) and write to BigQuery tables using Python.

Also, I have some hive tables in an on-premise Hadoop cluster, how do I transfer this data to BigQuery.

I couldn't find the right documentation or examples to achieve this.
Can you please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

I applied a solution in my project to provide such thing, you need to follow these steps:

1. Load data from `Google Cloud SQL` to `Google Cloud storage` in CSV by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export#examples).
2. Load the CSV data from `Google cloud storage` directly into `BigQuery` by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data).

Comment: The OP means an on-premiss DB and not a cloud-based DB like Google Cloud Storage

Comment: The question is how to read data from a database outside the GCP infrastructure