# How to read data from PostgreSQL database (JDBC) and write to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have my database in one of my project in GCP with shared VPC.

From a different project, I started google data flow, and tried to connect the database, but always get '*The connection attempt failed.*', since it couldn't find the hostname that I provided in my `application.yml`.

If I create a VM instance in this Big Query project (with shared VPC network), and install PostgreSQL client, I can connect to that database.

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020311/google-cloud-dataflow-how-to-read-data-from-a-database-and-write-to-bigquery), but I don't see the answer for connecting to database.

I also, tried by running maven compile with subnetworks parameter either [complete or short form URL](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#subnetwork_parameter), but still no luck.

Below is the command that I ran from cloudshell:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.myurl.spring.beam.pipeline.SpringBeamPipelineLauncher \
-Dexec.args="--project=test-big-query \
--stagingLocation=gs://test-big-query/test/ \
--runner=DataflowRunner \
--jobName=dataflow-dryrun \
--springContextClass=com.myurl.bi.gcdf.sqlloader.config.PipelineConfig \
--bootstrapOptionClass=com.myurl.spring.beam.pipeline.options.BootstrapOptions \
--entryPoint=com.myurl.bi.gcdf.sqlloader.SQLLoaderEntryPoint \
--subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/NAMEOFVPCHOSTPROJECT/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/NAMEOFVPCNETWORK"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you are specifying the name of the subnet and not the name of the vpc?

```
--subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/NAMEOFVPCHOSTPROJECT/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/MYSUBNET"
```

If you can reach your pgsql instance using a client in **MYSUBNET** then specifying the above parameter should work.

Comment: Hello Sameer, my apology. I did use the name of subnet of my shared VPC network. But still, it gives me the same error.